# State Value Stops Updating Within UseEffect Hook - Gatsby/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

State value `showMenu` is not updating within `useEffect` hook.

When testing, when the button is first clicked and the screen is touched to move, `showMenu` properly consoles to `true`. When the button is clicked a second time (and third, forth, etc) and the screen is touched to move, `showMenu` continues to console as `true` when it should alternate to `false`.

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false)

useEffect(_ => {
    const listener = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(showMenu, ' useEffect - touchmove')
    }

    showMenu
        ? document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', listener, {passive: false})
        : document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener)
}, [showMenu])

return (
    <button onclick={_ => {
        console.log(!showMenu, ' button click')
        setShowMenu(!showMenu)
    }} />
)
```

**Console Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the event of body is not properly removed, because listener is changed every time `useEffect`.

So you can return a function in `useEffect` to clear the previous `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (showMenu) {
        const listener = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(showMenu, ' useEffect - touchmove');
        };

        document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', listener, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener);
        }
    }
}, [showMenu]);
```

You can also read [cleaning-up-an-effect](https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) to learn more

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I could conditionally use the useEffect callback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your intent is, but what you are doing with `useEffect` is probably not what you're expecting. When `showMenu` is `false`, you're removing a `listener` function that has not been bound because objects are compared by reference in JS and `listener` is being redefined each time `showMenu` changes.

The typical way to unbind a listener when `useEffect` changes is to return a function that handles the cleanup from your `useEffect` callback. Like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const listener = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(showMenu, ' useEffect - touchmove')
  }

  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', listener, { passive: false })

  return () = {
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener, { passive: false })
  }
}, [showMenu])
```